# button is not clickable in versions < Lollipop

Tags: android

i have a basic layout which contains some views. When there is a network connection a RecyclerView is shown. When the user swipes to refresh and there is no connection a button and a textview, which are inside the basic layout  invisible at first place, become visible. The problem is that the button is not clickable in devices with Android version < Lollilop.

basic_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/listSurveysRlt"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">

<com.rey.material.widget.TextView
    android:id="@+id/codeDescTtv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/code_dest_txv_padding_bottom"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_above="@+id/sRetryBtn"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="@dimen/code_dest_txv_text_size"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<com.rey.material.widget.Button
    android:id="@+id/sRetryBtn"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/action_btn_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/action_btn_height"
    android:text="@string/retry"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:background="@drawable/ripple_drawable"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLlt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/completedSurveysRcV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/surveys_rcv_margin_top" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/noSurveysImv"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/no_surveys_imv_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/no_surveys_imv_height"
    android:src="@drawable/no_surveys"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/no_surveys_imv_margin_top"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ongoing" />

<com.rey.material.widget.TextView
    android:id="@+id/noSurveysTxv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/noSurveysImv"
    android:text="@string/no_completed"
    android:textSize="@dimen/no_surveys_txv_text_size"
    android:textColor="@color/no_surveys_txv_color"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

the method which transforms the corrensponding views from visible to invisible and vice versa:

```
private void onErrorBackgroundView(int code) {
    listSurveysRlt.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.view_color));
    completedSurveysRcV.setVisibility(View.GONE); //RecyclerView
    codeDescTtv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //TextView
    retryBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //not clickable button 
    codeDescTtv.setText(getResources().getString(inputValidationCodes.get(code)));
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to also specify `retryBtn.setEnabled(true);`?

Comment: where is the code to add click listener on the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging i found out the reason behind this strange behavior of the framework. The culprit was the SwipeRefreshLayout that blocked ui clicks ,so by setting the visibility of this layout to gone every time the user swipes the screen and restore the visibility when connection is available solved the issue. If anyone knows why this was happening in versions < Lollipop, it would be much helpful.